# Many browsers are needed but it takes too much memory

Tags: c#, memory, browser

Hi I am working on an application in which I need almost 10 `webBrowsers` which render when some button is clicked. Now this amount of browsers takes too much memory on `RAM`. Is there any way to reduce the memory consumption with the mentioned number of browsers?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be... why do you need 10 browsers? Perhaps if you describe what your program is doing we can suggest another way.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you could try using multi-threading?

Comment: Are you sure it is the amount of browsers or is it the complexity of the pages they are rendering? How do you know it is TOO much (and how much is it)?

Comment: @Darkshadw, multi-threading is hardly ever a solution to a memory issue.

Comment: actually my app renders top 10 articles in the web browsers. This amount of web browsers is required.
I am using background worker to render these browsers. I have monitored it through task manager that it takes the memory from 400 to 500 mb

Comment: Write a bit of html that uses `frameset` so you need only one browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a lot you can do to reduce memory consumption depending on where the memory is being used.

It depends on what is taking the memory, you could try launching the browsers in No-addon mode which would save some memory, additionally if the memory consumption is increasing becuase of data in the pages stored in the ViewState of the page then moving data from the ViewState to the session would help with this.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make sure you dispose or reuse any WBCs - don't worry about it. 100 megs in the task manager is not worth worrying about.